# Is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} {{n}\choose{k}}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+2}$ equal to $\frac{1}{2n+2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

On p. 146 of *[Principles of Mathematical Analysis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjgyOyv17bRAhVMSyYKHbtdB2IQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnotendur.hi.is%2Fvae11%2F%25C3%259Eekking%2Fprinciples_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf&usg=AFQjCNECF1k5HDQP-wpHD5DgbEGJC54fOQ)*, Rudin claims that $\int_{0}^{1} x(1-x^2)^ndx=\frac{1}{2n+2}$. But evaluating the integral I found it equal to $$\int_{0}^{1}x(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}(-x^2)^k)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}(-1)^{k}x^{2k+1}dx=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^{2k+2}}{2k+2}$$ evaluated at $x=1$, which equals $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} {{n}\choose{k}}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+2}$. So now I'm just wondering, why is this equal to $\frac{1}{2n+2}$?

Comment: If you substitute $x^2\mapsto u$ in the integral, then I'd say you've just proven the identity in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+2}&=\frac{1}2\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}k(-1)^k\\
&=\frac{1}2\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^k\\
&=\frac{1}{2n+2}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k(-1)^{k-1}\\
&=\frac{-1}{2n+2}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k(-1)^k1^{n+1-k}\\
&=\frac{-1}{2n+2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k(-1)^k1^{n+1-k}-\binom{n+1}0(-1)^01^{n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{-1}{2n+2}\left((-1+1)^{n+1}-1\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2n+2}
\end{align*}$$

by the binomial theorem.

Comment: @Dr.MV: No, actually, since I started writing it before you posted and didn't see your hint until after I finished writing, editing, and posting the final version.

Comment: No worry.  You're the most prolific user herein.  I was merely pointing out the flow of presentation is aligned with the hint I posted.  And Happy New Year!  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: Same to you! (One-finger typing on a Kindle tablet is painfully slow, especially when you're typing mathematics.)

Comment: I completely understand.  I'm on a "smart phone" and watching the championship football game.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

Note that we can write

$$\frac{1}{2k+2}\,\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{2n+2}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

Then, substitute this into the summation, shift the index from $k$ to $k'=k+1$ so the new summation limits are $k'=1$ to $k'=n+1$, and use $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k=0$.

Comment: There must be a typo. Did you mean $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{2k+2}{2n+2}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ or $\frac1{2k+2}\binom{n}{k}=\frac1{2n+2}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$?

Comment: @robjohn Indeed.  I meant the latter.  Thank you for catching this; I've edited.  And Happy New Year.  -Mark

Comment: Hmm, following your hint we have $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+2}=\sum_{k'=1}^{n+1}{{n+1}\choose{k+1}}\frac{(-1)^k}{2n+2}$ (noting that k'=k+1) $=\frac{1}{2n+2}\sum_{k'=1}^{n+1}{{n+1}\choose{k'}}(-1)^{k'-1}=\frac{1}{2n+2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n+1}\choose{k+1}}(-1)^{k}$. Now I'm not sure exactly where $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{{n}\choose{k}}(-1)^k=0$ comes in, or why this identity holds. We have $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{{n}\choose{k}}(-1)^k=1-n+{{n}\choose{2}}- \dots + {{n}\choose{n+1}}$ (assuming n+1 even). Why does this equal 0 (and if it does, how does that help us)?

Comment: @Rasputin Note that $$\sum_{k'=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k'}(-1)^{k'-1}=1+\sum_{k'=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k'}(-1)^{k'-1}=1$$The sum from $k'=0$ since it is the binomial expansion of $(-1)\times (1+(-1))^{n+1}$.

Comment: Great, thank you! That makes perfect sense. Guess I will just keep trying to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{{n+1}\choose{k}}(-1)^k=0$ then . . .

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  I would suggest using induction to prove the binomial theorem.  And wishing you a very Happy New Year! -Mark

Comment: Right, got it! Thanks, to you as well!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the substitution $1-x^{2}=t$ to change the integral to $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}\,dt=\frac{1}{2n+2}$$ But you seem more interested in the link between your sum and value of integral in a direct manner as given in answers by Brian Scott and Dr. MV.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very interested in more simple solutions as well. Just wondering though, how does this substitution change the integral to $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}t^ndt$? Wouldn't it change the integral to $\int_{0}^{1}(\sqrt{1-t})(t^n)dt$ (or something like that -- I'm not too sure how to deal with whether it's $+ \sqrt{1-t}$ or $-\sqrt{1-t}$ . . .)?

Comment: @Rasputin: differentiate $1-x^{2}=t$ to get $-2x\,dx=dt$ and hence the part $x\, dx$ gets replaced by $-dt/2$. There is no need to replace just $x$ by $\sqrt{1-t}$.

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense, thank you! Would we then have that it equals $-\frac{1}{2n+2}$ though because $x$ gets replaced by $-dt/2$ instead of just $dt/2$?

Comment: @Rasputin : note that the limits $0,1$ for $x$ correspond to limits $1,0$ for $t$ and reversing them again to $0,1$ adds one more minus sign which fixes $-dt/2$.

Comment: Ah right that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An overkill. [The Melzak's identity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07006) tell us that $$f\left(x+y\right)=y\dbinom{y+n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{f\left(x-k\right)}{y+k}
 $$ where $f$ is an algebraic polynomial up to dergee $n$, x,y\in\mathbb{R},\, y\neq-1,\dots-n
 . So taking $f\equiv1
 $ and $y=1$ we get $$1=\dbinom{1+n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{1}{1+k}
 $$ hence $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{1}{1+k}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{n+1}}\tag{1}
 $$ now you have only to multiply both side of $(1)$ by $1/2$.